# Is there any way in java to return the same collection type after using stream on the collection?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I want to operate on a collection and get a mapped collection of the original one with the same type.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
public <Ty extends Collection<Value>> Ty getClone(Ty c) {
    return c.stream().map(this::getClone).collect(Collectors.toCollection(c::new)); //Cannot resove constructor 'Ty'
}
```

Is the type of generics I am trying to use possible? If it is, how would I have to change my method?

Comment: are you trying to recursively cal the method using `this::getClone`?

Comment: ah actually not, that's another function that happened to have the same name :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with the arguments you are currently supplying.

You can do it if you pass in a `Supplier<Ty>` (or, more generally, a `Supplier<? extends Ty>`):

```
public <Ty extends Collection<Value>> Ty getClone(Ty c, Supplier<? extends Ty> supplier) {
    return c.stream().map(this::getClone).collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
}
```

Comment: Note, that `.map(this::getClone)` might have been a recursive call.

Comment: @Naman that would require `Value` to be assignable to `Ty extends Collection<Value>` which is very hard to achieve and of little practical use. Creating a real tree node type with a built-in clone operation would make much more sense then.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This is not possible as you've written it.

In Java, it's always possible that your collection wouldn't support this operation at all.  It could be a class that implements a single collection and can never be reused for anything else.  That's not exactly common, but it's certainly possible.

You can certainly pass in your own `Supplier`.  Or you can do `instanceof` on every collection type you want to support and explicitly make your own supplier, and throw if it's not a recognized type.  But the API you've described, as written, is not possible in full generality.